# Как с помощью json_decode разобрать только первый уровень JSON?

Tags: php, json, vkontakte-api

В VK API есть загрузка фотографий для товаров ([vk.com/dev](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0)). Одним из шагов загрузки является получение от VK такого JSON:

> {"server":625831,"photo":"[{\"photo\":\"8d81799f90:w\",\"sizes\":[[\"s\",\"625831075\",\"45839\",\"-5fbUeQq1YY\",75,56],[\"m\",\"625831075\",\"4583a\",\"G8yAYbsk7M4\",130,97]]}]","hash":"8954a4da5ba06d4e","crop_data":"oAAmMpwAAAAAlTWyjA","crop_hash":"729155760247b391134"}

Документация уточняет что разбирать нужно только первый уровень, внутренние элементы тоже могут оказаться JSON, но разбирать их не надо:

> Обратите внимание, что ответ сервера всегда приходит в формате JSON, а
>   поля server, photo, hash, crop_data и crop_hash в нем содержат строки,
>   внутренний формат которых может изменяться со временем. В частности,
>   строка photo может содержать другой JSON-объект, который не следует
>   декодировать, разбирать на части или иным образом модифицировать.

Вопрос: как с помощью стандартной json_decode разобрать только первый уровень JSON, оставив остальные строками?

Для того чтоб нам разговаривать на одном языке упростим ситуацию.

```
<?php
$data = [
    'alice'=>[
        'age'=>30,
        'sex'=>'f',
    ],
    'bob'=>[
        'age'=>25,
        'sex'=>'m',
    ],
];

$json = json_encode($data);
//{"alice":{"age":30,"sex":"f"},"bob":{"age":25,"sex":"m"}}

$decoded = json_decode($json);
//набор объектов stdClass. Каждый объект имеет свои свойства. Json разложен полностью
$decodedAssoc = json_decode($json, TRUE);
//Ассоциативный массив. Json разложен полностью
$decodedDepth = json_decode($json, TRUE, 1);
//NULL Вложенных уровней больше чем указано
```

Comment: а что `$response['server']`, `$response['photo']`, `$response['hash']` и т.д. уже не работают?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Работают, но эти данные надо потом назад в VK отправлять, поэтому если в photo окажется JSON, то его надо отправить в оригинальном варианте, а не разобранном, как это сделает json_decode()

Comment: так в поле фото и так будет содержаться строка с json'ом пока вы не сделаете так `json_decode($response['photo'], true);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский без $assoc = true json_decode возвращает объекты stdClass, внутренний json раскладывается на свойства

Comment: Госпади. вы вообще пользуетесь `print_r` или `var_dump` ? или все интуитивно делаете?.... от указания `true` ничего не изменится... у вас все также будет строка в том поле.... только доступ будет через `$response->photo`

Comment: Доступ изменится, это да, но внутренний JSON тоже будет разобран и станет свойствами объекта. К примеру про Alice и Bob: var_dump($decoded->alice) = object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["age"]=> int(30) ["sex"]=> string(1) "f" }, а ожидается что var_dump($decoded->alice) = {"age":30,"sex":"f"}

Comment: @atom-22 я вам в ответе все это написал, чтоб виднее было. вы смотрели?

Comment: @atom-22 не надо мне приводить свои данные разобранные по `decode` вы посмотрите данные по декодированию **конкретно данного json'a** и увидите всю проблему. Данный json он будет так разбирать вглубь.... а все потому, что он сформирован по-другому...не так, как вы свой тест сформировали

Comment: @atom-22 `Для того чтоб нам разговаривать на одном языке упростим ситуацию.` - видите к чему приводит упрощение ситуации, а не проверки и видении текущей ситуации как она есть? А все потому, что вы свой упрощенный пример изначально неправильно сформировали... не так как ВК это сделал и прислал.... вы забыли доп. поле, которое также закодировано в `json` ...... для наглядности: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b32c-369d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а вообще-то, если бы вы проверили, то api делает всё честно, внутренние json'ы переданы как строковые элементы, а не как чать структуры.

```
print_r(json_decode($str, true));
```

результат

```
Array
(
    [server] => 625831
    [photo] => [{"photo":"8d81799f90:w","sizes":[["s","625831075","45839","-5fbUeQq1YY",75,56],["m","625831075","4583a","G8yAYbsk7M4",130,97]]}]
    [hash] => 8954a4da5ba06d4e
    [crop_data] => oAAmMpwAAAAAlTWyjA
    [crop_hash] => 729155760247b391134
)
```